# In an array like array[i] how can you make a condition to see the value of [i] and exit a loop once its higher than a certain value?

Tags: c

If my accounts[MAX] has a MAX of 10 and in a loop to prompt the user to input account #s in account[MAX] how do I make a code to see if the amount of accounts has exceeded 10, and tell the user that the max # of accounts has been inputted and no longer accepts input?

here is my do while loop

```
do
{
printf ("Options Available: \n");
printf ("\n 1 - Enter a transaction");
printf ("\n 2 - View the general journal");
printf ("\n 3 - View the balance sheet");
printf ("\n q - Quit the program\n");

printf ("\nPlease enter 1, 2, 3 or q: ");

    option = validateoption();

    if (option == '1')
    {
        printf ("\nEnter an account number (between 1000 and 3999): ");
        accounts[i] = validateaccount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter d (debit) or c (credit): ");
        debcred[i] = validatedebcred();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("Enter transaction amount: ");
        amount[i] = validateamount();
        printf ("\n");

        printf ("\n");

        i++;
        totalinput++;
    }

    if (option == '2')
        journal(accounts, debcred, amount, &totalinput);

    if (option == '3')
        balancesheet(accounts, debcred, amount, &totalinput);

} while (option != 'q');
```

And lets just say it works if you input 1, 2, 3 or q. Now in the accounts[i], if the # of accounts has exceeded 10, what can i write to tell the user that the max number of acounts has been entered and to not accept more input?

my validateaccount function:

```
long validateaccount() {  // VALIDATE INPUT FOR ACCOUNT # IN TRANSACTION FUNCTION

int keeptrying = 1, rc;
 long i;
char after;

do
{
    rc = scanf ("%ld%c", &i, &after);

    if (rc == 0)
    {
        printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
        clear();
    }
        else if (after != '\n')
        {
            printf (" **Trailing characters try again: ");
            clear();
        }
            else if (i < 1000 || i > 3999)
            {
                printf (" **Invalid input try again: ");
            }
                else
                {
                    keeptrying = 0;
                }

} while (keeptrying == 1);

return i;

}
```

Comment: Excuse me shouldn't it be If, Else If, and Else? not so many ifs (It seems weird)

Comment: Or a nice switch statement... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if (option == '1')
```

with

```
if (option == '1' && totalinput < MAX)
```

And option 1 is disabled when the maximum number has been reached.

You might want to add the check earlier as well, so you do not `printf()` option 1 if it has been disabled.

**Note**: You have both `i` and `totalinput`. I think it would be better (more understandable) if you remove `i` and only use `totalinput`. (as `totalinputs` is more descriptive than `i`)

Comment: Ok that works in that it stops accepting input, but how can I add the printf option in that to print a message when the input amount is too high? Cause right now it just re enters the original loop without printing anything

Comment: By adding the same check (if-statement) in `validateoption()` so entering a 1 is ignored if it is disabled... Or pass a boolean value (true when the option is available, false when it is disabled) to the function, if you do not have `totalinput` available in the function (which you don't)

Comment: sorry im not sure how to understand that! In my validateoption() function i added an else if statement if totalinput > 10 printf something and added a pointer to that function pointing to totalinput but still it didn't printf anything!

Comment: After you grab the user input, you should check if option 1 is disabled. If so, tell the user and ask for a new value (which you already do if the user entered 4, I suppose?).

Comment: what is the condition to check if option 1 is disabled? And in the main loop or in the validateoption function? Everything im trying just skips the inputting and reruns the 1,2,3,q loop but doesn't print anything if the totalinput is too high

Comment: ok I did if (option == '1' && totalinput >= MAX)
            printf (" ** HELLO\n"); .. and it works so far...thanks